# jQuery DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Code: On click of the submit button, once users enter the text, the application hits the rest API which has data in the format of JSON.The code should process the JSON data and from a jquery data table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#txt').click(function () {
                    var requestData = $('#txtid').val();
                    var url = '<my api url>' + requestData;
                    $('#resultDiv1').dataTable({
                        "processing": true,
                        "ajax": url,
                        "columns": [
                            {"": "account.id"},
                            {"": "account.rel"},
                            {"": "account.fin"},
                            {"": "account.date"}
                        ],
                        "dom": "Bfrtip",
                        "buttons": [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ]
                    });
                });
            });
```

I am trying to form a Jquery data table from a restful API but getting the below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
            at jquery.dataTables.min.js:48
            at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
            at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:35)
            at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
            at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
            at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
            at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

Ajax Response: Here is the format of Ajax coming from RestAPI:

```
  {
      "account": [
        {
          "id": "1", 
          "rel": "P", 
          "fin": "abc", 
          "date": "2001-01-05"
        }, 
        {
           "id": "2", 
          "rel": "P", 
          "fin": "def", 
          "date": "2001-02-05"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "3", 
          "rel": "R", 
          "fin": "ghi", 
          "date": "2019-01-05"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Can someone please throw light on why this is coming and what changes do I need to make?

Comment: Please show a sample of your Ajax response.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com : edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference` (IE) or `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` (other browsers) with jQuery DataTables usually means that the plugin cannot access the data in response from Ajax request.

Use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to specify data property (`account`) in your Ajax response containing the data.

Your code was also missing proper [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) options.

Change your initialization options as follows:

```js
$('#resultDiv1').dataTable({
    // ... skipped other options ...
    "ajax": {
       "url": url,
       "dataSrc": "account"
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "id"},
        {"data": "rel"},
        {"data": "fin"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ]
});
```

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) for more information on this and other common console errors.